# jQuery not affecting the right item

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a form, viewable here: http://dev.calgunsfoundation.org/get-help/hotline/

And, I have some jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {

          jQuery('.ginput_container label').each(function(i,e){
              fielddesc = jQuery('<div>').append(jQuery(e).clone()).remove().html();
              jQuery(e).siblings('.ginput_container input:email').before(fielddesc);
              jQuery(e).siblings('.ginput_container input:text').before(fielddesc); //moves sub label above input fields
              jQuery(e).siblings('.ginput_container select').before(fielddesc); //moves sub label above select fields (e.g. country drop-down)
              jQuery(e).siblings('.ginput_container .gfield_radio input').after(fielddesc); //keep label above radio buttons
              jQuery(e).siblings('.ginput_container .gfield_checkbox input').after(fielddesc);
              jQuery(e).remove();
          });

      });
    </script>
```

Problem is that this line:

```
jQuery(e).siblings('.ginput_container input:email').before(fielddesc);
```

doesn't seem to work at all.

(It's currently commented out on the site itself.)

When I enable that line, the form doesn't show up. When I disable it, everything works (but, of course the 'Enter Email' and 'Confirm Email' labels don't show up correctly.

The code, when the jQuery isn't running is shown here:

```
<li id="field_3_3" class="gfield gfield_contains_required">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_3_3">
        Email
            <span class="gfield_required">
                *
            </span>
    </label>
    <div class="ginput_complex ginput_container" id="input_3_3_container">
        <span id="input_3_3_1_container" class="ginput_left">
            <input type="email" name="input_3" id="input_3_3" value="" tabindex="17">
                <label for="input_3_3">
                    Enter Email
                </label>
        </span>
        <span id="input_3_3_2_container" class="ginput_right">
            <input type="email" name="input_3_2" id="input_3_3_2" value="" tabindex="18">
                <label for="input_3_3_2">
                    Confirm Email
                </label>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

It seems like I'm targeting the right thing, I want the input:email and to move the label that's currently BELOW the input, to now be ABOVE the input. But, obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: nitpick, e is normally used for event object, makes your code confusing.

Comment: Sorry. I suck at jQuery. :(

Comment: Like @epascarello said, it's a nitpick but certainly remember it as you learn more about jQuery. As easy as jQuery is, it still takes time to wrap your head around it fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:email isn't a valid :selector -- this is the root of the problem
    `jQuery(e).siblings('.ginput_container input:email')`

you could use the id selector instead for those two inputs :

```
jQuery(e).siblings('#input_3_3, #input_3_3_2')`
```

or generic :

```
jQuery(e).siblings('input[type=email]')
```

generic for both text/email :

```
jQuery(e).siblings('input[type=email], input[type=text]')
```

Comment: When I change it, the page doesn't load at all.

Comment: He isn't selecting it. He is creating a jQuery wrapper around an in memory div

Comment: Basically, I'd like the email labels "Enter email" and "confirm email" to show up ABOVE the input box instead of below.

Comment: Updated the fiddle above to reflect your change. You were on the right track using before() above but you don't need to remove the original object before() moves objects in the dom if you supply an element.

Comment: Your change doesn't work given the whole form. I need it to be a bit more 'choosy' about what it moves and what it doesn't.

The best answer would take what I have and simply expand on it/fix it. When I use your jQuery code, the form doesn't display at all. :(

Comment: Slimmed down my response to the specifics why you were getting the fail when that line wasn't commented.

Comment: Sweet.. BUT, this should work on any form (i.e. it may not be input_3_3 -- any other idea on how to choose just the 'email' field? :)  (We have a number of fields, and they need to all work dynamically..)

BUT, your solution works, which means it's getting the wrong selector for some reason; but input:email is correct. No?

Comment: :email isn't a valid selector - the full list of selectors is here : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ -- if you want to skip the ids and be more generic you can do : `$('input[type=email]')` if you're looking to do this above all email + text : `$('input[type=email], input[type=text]')`

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was missing.. :)